# Manifest merger failed while adding new library

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest, manifest-merging

I am trying to include "TedBottomPicker" library into my project. After I added library in gradle and do sync. Then I got manifest merger failed error. I checked and included `tools:replace:"android:authorities"` and `tools:replace="android:resource"` but it didn't work.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.f.f">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<application
    android:name=".AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".listdisplay"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_listdisplay"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar1" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PostActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" />

  <provider
        android:name=".fp"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.share"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
            tools:replace="android:resource"/>
    </provider>

<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.vansuita.pickimage.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/picker_provider_paths" />
      </provider>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCG_a_xOn9SNyQLPBCHrdSPgu49MHbACdA" />
       </application>
```

The error i received in Android Manifest.

```
Merging Errors: Error: Attribute meta-data#android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS@resource value=(@xml/picker_provider_paths) from AndroidManifest.xml:95:17-55 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:21:17-55 value=(@xml/provider_paths). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:105:13-107:65 to override. app main manifest (this file), line 94
```

How can i include this library into my project.

Answer (score 0):

Do these and see if it works now:

```
<application
    android:name=".AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
    tools:replace="android:resource">
```

and make your gradle like this:

```
android {
     ...
     defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
        ...
     }
    ...
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '27.1.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add provider n your manifest to use that Api
**example**

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="app.{idOfYourApp}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
            tools:replace="android:resource" />
    </provider>
```